# NFS slow throughput

Tags: ubuntu, performance, nfs

I have experienced some issues with less-than-expected throughput with NFS. After examining a number of options (endless googling), including raid setup, network interfaces etc, I wanted to test a basic setup, exporting a ramdisk mounted on /media/ramdisk and accessing it through localhost.

The tests with the ramdisk shows the same performance issue pattern as with my SSD RAID0 NFS export, with a massive performance hit while accessing via NFS, and both the SSD raid and the ramdisk maxes out at approx. 13K IOPS read, and 4K IOPS write.

Server:

Ubuntu 18.04, fully updated. VM with 5 GB ram, and 8 processors. (Host cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4800)

Content of /etc/exports:

```
/media/ramdisk       *(rw,async,no_subtree_check,fsid=1)
```

Mounted via:

```
sudo mount 127.0.0.1:/media/ramdisk /mnt/ramdisk -o async
```

Output of mount command:

`127.0.0.1:/media/ramdisk on /mnt/ramdisk type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=127.0.0.1,local_lock=none,addr=127.0.0.1)`

Using fio to test the speed of the ramdisk without NFS with the following command:

`sudo fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=0 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=test1 --filename=/media/ramdisk/test --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --size=4G --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=75`

I get:

```
read: IOPS=283k, BW=1107MiB/s (1160MB/s)(3070MiB/2774msec)
write: IOPS=94.7k, BW=370MiB/s (388MB/s)(1026MiB/2774msec)
cpu          : usr=21.89%, sys=78.07%, ctx=5, majf=0, minf=7
```

Very fast, as expected

Testing via NFS with the following command:

`sudo fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=0 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=test2 --filename=/mnt/ramdisk/test --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --size=4G --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=75`

I get:

```
read: IOPS=12.7k, BW=49.6MiB/s (51.0MB/s)(3070MiB/61951msec)
write: IOPS=4239, BW=16.6MiB/s (17.4MB/s)(1026MiB/61951msec)
cpu          : usr=5.24%, sys=21.16%, ctx=786004, majf=0, minf=5
```

I am monitoring the system with atop during the test, and neither CPU nor network are particularly stressed during the test.

Using dd directly on the ramdisk with:

`sudo dd if=/media/ramdisk/test of=/dev/null bs=1M iflag=nocache status=progress`

I get:

`4294967296 bytes (4.3 GB, 4.0 GiB) copied, 0.691044 s, 6.2 GB/s`

Doing the same via NFS (/mnt/ramdisk/test), I get:

`4294967296 bytes (4.3 GB, 4.0 GiB) copied, 2.58302 s, 1.7 GB/s`

I have increased RPCNFSDCOUNT to 64

Running iperf on localhost, I get

```
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  64.6 GBytes  55.5 Gbits/sec
```

So apparently network throughput is good.

So what can be holding back the NFS performance?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> sudo fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=0 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=test1 --filename=/media/ramdisk/test --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --size=4G --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=75
> ```

Oh no :-(, you're using `--iodepth=64` with the `libaio` ioengine and `direct=0` so this command likely won't behave as you're expecting! See the [warning in the `fio` help/manual about failing to use `direct=1` when using `libaio` ioengine](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-ioengine):

> **libaio**
>
> Linux native asynchronous I/O. Note that **Linux may only support queued behavior with non-buffered I/O (set direct=1 or buffered=0)**. This engine defines engine specific options. [emphasis added]

so `libaio` is likely acting as if `iodepth=1`... (see https://github.com/axboe/fio/issues/512#issuecomment-356604533 for a more detailed explanation)

> So what can be holding back the NFS performance?

I'm afraid the fio command job you created is holding you back - maybe you need to use different options and/or a different I/O engine?

PS: You are very unlikely to be pushing enough I/O such that `--gtod_reduce=1` will make any difference to you...